Want to solve Equation for x
Below equation is quite straightforward but I couldn't figure out how to solve directly.and also I have tried in wolframalpha equation solver which did not give satisfactory answer. Please help me with the finding the root/s of the equation and explain how can we solve the equation straightforward without trial and error.
$$x=((\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x)^2+2(\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x)x+4)/50$$

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe the quadratic formula can be used to simplify the quadratic of the square root expression

$$x=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x)^2+2(\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x)x+4}{50}$$
Expand the square to get
$$x=\frac{x^2+50x-4+x^2-2x^2+4}{50}\\\implies x=x$$
This seems to be an identity. This is true when $x$ satisfies the domain of $\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x)^2+2(\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x)x+4}{50}$
Which means $$x^2+50x-4≥0$$
$$\implies (x+25+\sqrt{629})(x-25+\sqrt{629})≤0$$
Thus $$x\in (-\infty,-25-\sqrt{629}]\cup[-25+\sqrt{629},\infty)$$

You've missed out a factor of $x$ on the second term in the numerator.

In fact $x=0$ is a forbidden value...

@JeanMarie I've completed missed out something, let me correct it

Let $y:=\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}-x$.
$$x=(y^2+2xy+4)/50$$
$$\iff y^2+2xy+4-50x=0$$
$$\iff y=-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}$$
$$\iff y=-x\pm(y+x)$$
$$\impliedby y=-x+(y+x)$$
So, if your are solving for $x\in\Bbb R$, the solutions are all the real numbers $x$ such that
$x^2+50x-4\ge0$,
i.e. $(x+25)^2\ge629$,
i.e.
$$x\le-25-\sqrt{629}\text{ or }x\ge-25+\sqrt{629}.$$
However, in an algebraic context where $\sqrt~$ denotes any square root, in any field $K$ (which may as well be $\Bbb C$ as, for instance, a finite field with characteristic $>5$), the solutions are all $x\in K$ such that $x^2+50x-4$ is a square.  (Recall that in $\Bbb C$, every number is a square.)

I think it holds for all $x$, if you allow square roots of negative numbers.

Of course (as my calculation shows), but the square root sign usually does not allow this.

I agree, but it doesn't seem to bother the users who are promoting $x=0$ as a solution.

@GerryMyerson I had completely missed out the x that was multiplied to the intermediate term. I've edited it now :)

@GerryMyerson Yes, I didn't alert Gwen because I expected them to correct their two mistakes when reading my answer: that forgotten $x$, and a missing second term when expanding the central term $2\left(\sqrt{x^2+50x-4}\color{red}{-x}\right)x$ in the numerator.
